# create an array of time jobs based on customer weekly schedule

Tags: javascript, date, datetime

My customer specified weekly schedules (mondays at 2pm, fridays at 3pm, fridays also at 4pm, etc.). My function `foo()` needs to be called at these times. They will then say "Call foo() using this schedule" **but only for a number of specified months**.

So I have **their chosen schedule** (day is 1-7 for mon-sun):

```
const scheduleArray = [{day: '1', hour: '11', minute: '34'},{...}]
```

Which I need to convert into an array of **real** days in the format I'm thinking:

```
 const scheduleArrayForFooFunction = [{
    month: '3', 
    date: '16', 
    hour: '11', 
    minute: '34'},{...}]
```

Any recommendations on how to convert this? I'm having difficulties. Or is there a javascript library that will do it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[momentjs.com](http://momentjs.com) is what you need.

To get first Monday of the current month for instance

```
moment().startOf('month').add(1, 'week').add(-1, 'day').day('1')
```

(Last call in the chain `day('1')` for Monday I used string because of your format but it can be just a number)

Then you can use `add(1, 'week')` to get other Mondays. And check range of months as you need.

**UPDATE**

RobG asked if there is simpler way. Obviously it could be simplified

```
moment().startOf('month').add(6, 'day').day('1')
```

But I think it's not so clear why we add 6 days.

Comment: That seems like a convoluted way to get the first Monday of the month (5 function calls). Surely there's a simpler way?

Comment: @RobG I've provided an update. Take a look. If you know better way let us know.